# jQuery UI does not work with Mootools after calling noConflict()

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery

I have a web page requires both jQuery and Mootools to function. The conflict between these 2 libraries were solved when adding `jQuery.noConflict();` to the script.

But I also want to popup a jQuery dialog window when the jQuery user input validation fails.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function OnButton1()
{
var noOfChecked = jQuery("input:checked").length; 
if(noOfChecked > 0)
{
        jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }                   
            }
        });

  return false;}  }
```

The problem is that the jQuery dialog window did not popup. It seems that the `noConflict()` doesn't solve the problem. But the strange thing is that the jQuery is  actually working because the validation using jQuery is actually functioning. So I just don't understand why jQuery is working but jQuery UI is not.

So can anyone please help me to get my jQuery UI working with Mootools? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Michael, please include a URL or full example of the source in order to show the complete problem. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you use a version of mootools later than 1.2.3 and that you load it AFTER you load jquery. this will ensure that mootools will NOT overwrite the `$` and will revert back to `document.id`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be working with jQuery.noConflict() but sometimes you need to change jquery name completely.

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

After that use $j instead of $.

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries